# Snowflake connector.connect breaks with an error message that tells me nothing

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I installed the snowflake connector via the command: `pip3 install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]==2.3.3 asn1crypto==1.3.0 --user`

I attempted to connect via:

```
from snowflake import connector

        con = connector.connect(
                  host='.snowflakecomputing.com',
                  user='THE USER I USE FOR LOGGING IN TO MY TRIAL ACCOUNT',
                  password='THE PASSWORD I USE FOR LOGGING IN TO MY TRIAL ACCOUNT',
                  account='zka81761.us-east-1',
                  warehouse='COMPUTE_WH',
                  database='DEMO_DB',
                  schema='PUBLIC',
                  protocol='https',
                  port=443)
```

When executing the above code it just hangs for several minutes then I get an error:

`snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 250003: Failed to execute request: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)`

The longer version is:

```
  File "tests/integration_tests/data_sources/test_snowflake_ds.py", line 6, in test_snowflake_ds
    ds = SnowflakeDS(query='SELECT * FROM HEALTHCARE_COSTS', host='.snowflakecomputing.com', user='GEORGE3D6', password='a passwordd', account='zka81761.us-east-1', warehouse='COMPUTE_WH', database='DEMO_DB', schema='PUBLIC', protocol='https', port=443)
  File "/home/george/mindsdb_native/mindsdb_native/libs/data_types/data_source.py", line 13, in __init__
    df, col_map = self._setup(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/mindsdb_native/mindsdb_native/libs/data_sources/snowflake_ds.py", line 21, in _setup
    port=port)
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/__init__.py", line 52, in Connect
    return SnowflakeConnection(**kwargs)
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 219, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.__open_connection()
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 613, in __open_connection
    self._authenticate(auth_instance)
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 839, in _authenticate
    self.__authenticate(self.__preprocess_auth_instance(auth_instance))
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 869, in __authenticate
    session_parameters=self._session_parameters,
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/auth.py", line 209, in authenticate
    socket_timeout=self._rest._connection.login_timeout)
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 509, in _post_request
    _include_retry_params=_include_retry_params)
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 586, in fetch
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 676, in _request_exec_wrapper
    conn, full_url, cause)
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 706, in handle_invalid_certificate_error
    'errno': ER_FAILED_TO_REQUEST,
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 128, in errorhandler_wrapper
    connection.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
  File "/home/george/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 90, in default_errorhandler
    done_format_msg=error_value.get('done_format_msg'))
snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 250003: Failed to execute request: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label empty or too long)
```

This error message tells me nothing, any help would be appreicated

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#usage-notes-for-the-account-parameter-for-the-connect-method) on the python API the `host` field is no longer used so try removing that. Also, even if it was used, you haven't enclosed it properly in quotes:

**You have**: `host='.snowflakecomputing.com,`

**Should be**: `host='.snowflakecomputing.com',`

First, I'd see if removing the host completely fixes your issue since it shouldn't be used anyway.

Googling the error, and the error message itself, suggests that the issue is due to the URL being too long so I'd say the error is down to the fact that you haven't enclosed it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I used to connect snowflake from python like below:

```html
import snowflake.connector as sf

sfconnection = sf.connect(
                user='THE USER I USE FOR LOGGING IN TO MY TRIAL ACCOUNT',
                password='THE PASSWORD I USE FOR LOGGING IN TO MY TRIAL ACCOUNT',
                account='zka81761.us-east-1',
                warehouse='COMPUTE_WH',
                database='DEMO_DB',
                schema='PUBLIC')
```

Answer (score -2):

Apparently the docs are wrong and the `host` should now be the full URL (so, in my case `zka81761.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com`). That is to say, it should include the `account`.

Comment: Where did you read this in the docs? From what I can see it says that the `host` field isn't used at all.